# Compile multiple file types with one rule using makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

Lets assume I have a following makefile:

```
CPPFILES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJFILES := $(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o)

.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJFILES)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@
```

Now I would like to add support for *.cc files.
Is any possibility to expand line **%.o: %.cpp** to process both *.cpp and *.cc files in one line? I would expect something like: **%.o: %.cpp %.cc**.

Comment: Are you going to use the same compiler / command line to compile both .cc and .cpp files ?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same.

Comment: How about renaming all you .cc files into .cpp ?

Comment: Unfortunately not acceptable :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really just reinventing make's builtin rules, but the following should work

```
CCFILES     := $(wildcard *.cc)
CPPFILES    := $(wildcard *.cpp)
CCOBJFILES  := $(CCFILES:.cc=.o)
CPPOBJFILES := $(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o)
OBJFILES    := $(CCOBJFILES) $(CPPOBJFILES)

.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJFILES)

$(CCOBJFILES): %.o: %.cc
$(CPPOBJFILES): %.o: %.cpp
$(OBJFILES):
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@
```

With the builtin rules the above can be shortened to

```
CCFILES  := $(wildcard *.cc)
CPPFILES := $(wildcard *.cpp)

.PHONY: all
all: $(CCFILES:.cc=.o) $(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o)
```

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I was looking for. Moreover I didn't know about builtin rules. It is now even more smart and simple! Many thanks! :)